# Importing resources from dock or rail freight terminal?

Tags: simcity-2013

I need to do the exact same thing as [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110211/how-can-i-force-only-rail-export-of-goods-from-a-trade-port), but for **imports**. My neighbor sends tons of shoppers clogging my highway (I wish I could put down toll booths to tax them). I need oil for my power plant and ore for my smelter, but because the highway is basically completely disconnected at this point my resources never arrive even though I have both a rail freight terminal and a dock. Is it possible or is this city hopelessly screwed at this point?